# Groovlet classpath

Tags: groovy, groovlet

I'm writing a simple groovlet web application.

I have some groovy libraries (*.groovy), and all groovlets share this libraries.

Where should I put the groovy libraries for using in groovlets?

(I don't want to compile the library *.groovy because it could be changed many times)

Answer (score 0):

See "Setting up groovylets [sic]" [at this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlets).

To summarize the idea, assuming your webapp is called Pets:

- edit ~/webapps/Pets/WEB-INF/web.xml as described
- Groovy jars reside in ~/webapps/Pets/WEB-INF/lib as described
- your Groovlets (*.groovy files) reside in ~/webapps/Pets
- your custom Groovy jars/libraries reside in ~/webapps/Pets/WEB-INF/lib, per standard Servlet spec